# Using :visible and :first-child together in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the ":visible" and ":first-child" pseudo-selectors together in jQuery and it doesn't seem to be working out.  I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="action" style="display:none;">Item One</a>
    <a class="action">Item One</a>
    <a class="action">Item One</a>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery call:

```
$("div a.action:visible:first-child").addClass("first");
```

But it never seems to find the right element...it finds the first element but not the first **visible** element.  I've even tried swapping the selector order ":first-child:visible" instead of ":visible:first-child" and that doesn't work either.  Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need a first-child here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your selector

```
$("div a.action:visible:first-child").addClass("first");
```

matches only the *A* element only when it's the first-child of the parent DIV and when it is visible.

If you want to get the first visible *A* element, you should use the [.eq function](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index)

```
$("div a.action:visible").eq(0).addClass("first");
```

or the [:first pseudo-class](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first)

```
$("div a.action:visible:first").addClass("first");
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why `:visible:first-child` isn't working, but you can try

```
$("div a.action:visible").eq(0).addClass("first");
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the pseudo-class selector :first-child will only match the first child ever. It can not be further specified by adding a pseudo-class that it must also be visible. You might want to try writing

```
$("div a.action:visible:first").addClass("first");
```

instead of using the proper css pseudo-class. [JQuery documentation for :first](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `$( "div a.action:visible(:first-child))` as your selector, that is how jQuery specifies using multiple psuedo-selectors in its API documentation.