# Getting first visible element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to get the first visible element of a list using jQuery's `:first` and `:visible` pseudo-selectors, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/830611/165673 but it's not working:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FAY9q/4/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style="display:none;">Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('li:visible:first').css('background','blue');
```

The first item in each list should turn blue...

Comment: it seems to be working fine... background of Item A has changed

Comment: @Arun- If it were working then backgrounds of item A in first list AND item B in second list would change

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$('ul').find('li:visible:first').css('background','blue');
```

Currently your code is just getting the first visible `li` element on the page and setting the background colour. This code selects all `ul` elements then finds the first visible `li` within each of them and applies the style.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/FAY9q/5/

Comment: Strangely though, using `$('ul li:visible:first')` still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/FAY9q/7/ (Though it does when you use `$('ul').find('li:visible:first')`)

Comment: @Yarin - that will be because it's still just searching for the first visible `li` within a `ul`. The reason `.find()` works is that it finds the given selector within _each_ of the matched elements (in this case `ul`s).

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```
li:visible:not(:visible ~ :visible)
```

Comment: It matches the first visible list item as long as it isn't preceded by another visible item. It ensures that it's the first visible item and not just any visible item.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li:visible').eq(0).css('background','blue');
```

Comment: Thanks Yarin. It was my mistake, I didn't put find.